# Run multiple bat files within bat and passing arguments

Tags: batch-file

My problem is related to passing arguments to bat files. The first argument is passed correctly to the bat but the second time the argument is passed it's emtpy.

Example:

```
set comport = com4
call bat1.bat %comport%       ->comport is com4
if errorlevel 1 goto end
call bat2.bat %comport%       ->comport is empty
```

so after the first call of bat1.bat comport is empty. How can I make the call argument on the "main" bat level stay in memory after the call of the bat1.bat?

Comment: @Tomas: I must say, I cannot see how `%comport%` could evaluate to `com4` in the first place. It certainly could not be initialised by a `set` command where `=` is surrounded by spaces.

Comment: Yes, true. I should have written out that it's only pseudo code. It's more the general solution I'm after. comport is empty after calling the first bat.

Comment: @Tomas: And I guess you know for sure that `bat1.bat` cannot possibly reset the variable, don't you.

Comment: Is it really so? Bat1.bat is in another part of my project which cannot be modified and uses the same variable name %comport% internally, setting it to "" for some situations. And truly, that seems to clear the variable used in my file.

Comment: @Tomas: As expected. If you can, pick a different name (not used in other batch files, of course), and the problem will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set comport=com4
setlocal&(call bat1.bat %comport%)&endlocal
if errorlevel 1 goto end
call bat2.bat %comport%
:end
```

setlocal only works on WinNT4+, not DOS or Win9x, if you need to support those you would have to save %comport% to some other variable before calling bat1.bat and then restore the value